# How to map object value to observable array

Tags: angular, service, rxjs

I am receiving a JSON object from an http get request that has the array of objects I want in its value property.  As I am new to Angular 7 and Rxjs, I can't figure out how to map the array to my objects.

I am getting the data back as any, which brings back the data, to verify it is what I want.  I have gotten arrays of objects back from other API, but they have not been in the value attribute of a parent object.  When I use the tap message to the console, I see what I want to push to my array of objects, but I don't know the mapping syntax.

The JSON below is what I am getting back from the getTfsUsers() method from my user.service.ts.

Below that is the class (assignee.ts) I want to map the data to.

I would like getTfsUsers() to return an observable array of Assignee objects fro

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects(displayName,mail)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/blahblah",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "displayName": "Deer, John",
            "mail": "deer.john@myplace.org"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "displayName": "Doe, Jane",
            "mail": "doe.jane@myplace.org"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "displayName": "Fawn, Mike",
            "mail": "fawn.mike@myplace.org"
        }
     ]
}
```

```
getTfsUsers(): Observable<any>{
    const uri = `${this.groupsBaseUri}/${this.tfsUsersGroupId}/members/${this.displayNameMailFields}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
      .pipe(
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
      );
  }
```

```
export class Assignee {
    mail: string;
    displayName: string;
}
```

Is there a way to map the value attribute from the object being returned to an array of Assignees?

Comment: What is your desired output from that  object? Just the array within the `values` property?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.  Ideally I would get an array of Assignee objects (I don't need the "@odata.type") attribute in the values

Comment: Yup, got it! I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RxJS's [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator for that purpose, and have it nested within your `pipe()`. You will need to import the `map` operator on the top of your service, as shown below. Do note that it is different from JavaScript's [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
.
.

getTfsUsers(): Observable<any>{
    const uri = `${this.groupsBaseUri}/${this.tfsUsersGroupId}/members/${this.displayNameMailFields}`;
    return this.http.get<any>(uri)
      .pipe(
        map(data => data['value'].map(obj => {
          return {
            mail: obj.mail,
            displayName: obj.displayName
          };
        })),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => { return throwError(error); })
      );
  }
```